# Возврат результата рекурсии

Tags: c

Есть вот такая простенькая функция, для получения длинны строки.

```
int stringLength(char *string,int result){
     if(*string == 0){return result;}
     return stringLength(string+1,++result);
}
```

Для возврата результата я использую еще один параметр, который нужно передавать при вызове.

```
int length = 0;
length = stringLength(string,length);
```

Возможно сделать более красиво, т.е. например параметр, который по дефолту будет равен 0, и его не нужно будет указывать при вызове функции ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необычное применение рекурсии. В реальности этот код лучше преобразовать в цикл. Но если стоит задача именно использовать рекурсию, то можно от пользователя скрыть код

```
int length = 0;
length = stringLength(string,length);
```

поместив его в функцию. Например, так:

```
int stringLength(char *string) {
    int length = 0;
    return _stringLength(string,length);
}

int _stringLength(char *string,int result){
     if(*string == 0){return result;}
     return _stringLength(string+1,++result);
}
```

Comment: Кстати, она ж хвостовая. Компилятор же цикл сделает?

Comment: Может и сделает. Но все равно, ИМХО, цикл бы тут читался лучше.

Answer (score 2):

В Си нет параметров по умолчанию. Но в Си++ есть:

```
int stringLength(char *string, int result = 0) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Если посмотреть объявление стандартной функции `strlen`, которая возвращает длину строки, то можно увидеть, что она объявляется следующим образом

```
size_t strlen( const char *s );
```

Обратите внимание что например, указатель имеет квалификатор `const`, что позволяет находить длину также и константных строк, а возвращаемое значение имеет тип `size_t`.

Поэтому точно также следует объявить и рекурсивную функцию.

Ее определение очень простое

```
size_t stringLength( const char *s )
{
    return *s == 0 ? 0 : 1 + stringLength( s + 1 );
}
```

Comment: А вот `1+` - это уже не хвостовая рекурсия и циклом может и не стать...